# Unable to access Google Cloud from ASP.NET Core under IIS - : The Application Default Credentials are not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, firebase-admin

I am trying to connect to the Google Cloud FireBase Admin 2.4 from ASP.NET CORE 3.1.10.
Tried the following in a Controller where keyFilePath is the full path to a json file containing the credentials of a service account for Google:

> var defaultApp = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
> {
> Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(keyFilePath),
> });

Works well in development using Visual Studio, but failed with the following error when deployed
to a production server running IIS :

> System.InvalidOperationException: The Application Default Credentials are not available.

They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.

I then tried setting up the environment variable to get credentials without specifying a key file:
`Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault()`

Again, this works in development but fails under IIS.
I changed the ApplicationPool identity in IIS to run with admin privileges, but it still fails.

Another approach I tried is to use the same code and key file and run it in a Console App.  Now every thing works as expected in both development and production.
What is so special in IIS that makes it failed?

In yet another experiment, instead of using the key file directly, I changed to embedding the file as an embedded resource.  Once again, works great in development, but fails in production server under IIS.

Comment: What value is keyFilePath?

Comment: I set the value to  :  private readonly string _KeyFilePath = @"D:\LogFiles\Application\cathedra-8a0d41d0c96b.json";